# Svelte 3 Why the class is not being applied correctly

Tags: html, css, svelte

here's a [small example](https://svelte.dev/repl/c9e8b92c333548c4a585229a06e9c8b4?version=3.30.0). When mousemove over the frame, the div's inside smoothly change css props (transform and transition). ***Layer.svelte*** code:

```
<div
  style= "transform: rotateX(
    {-y * ratioTransform - ratioTransform*layerPosition*2}
    deg) rotateY(
    {x * ratioTransform + ratioTransform*layerPosition*2}
    deg); 
    transition: transform {0.4 + layerPosition*0.2}s ease-out;"
></div>
```

But if I create a style in js the smoothly change css props isn't working.

```
<script>
    let style = {
        transform: '',
        transition: ''
    };
    let styled = '';

    $: {
        style.transform = `transform:rotateX(${-y * ratioTransform - ratioTransform*layerPosition*2}deg) rotateY(${x * ratioTransform}deg)`;
        style.transition =`transition:transform 0.4 ${layerPosition*0.2}s ease-out`;
    }
    $: {
        styled = '';
        styled = style.transform + ';' + style.transition + ';';
    }
</script>

<div
    style="{styled}"
></div>
```

So what's the difference between the two ways?

Answer (score 0):

I think that on the latter you supposed to reference the `style` variable you created on your script.

So replace:

```
<div
    style="{styled}"
></div>
```

with:

```
<div
    style={styled}
></div>
```

And see if it does the trick.

Comment: I tried. Unfortunately this is not successful.

Comment: Can you add a reproducible code example? using codesandbox for example. It will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Ok, this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c9e8b92c333548c4a585229a06e9c8b4?version=3.30.0) or this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-worker-jvyj2?file=/Layer.svelte)

Comment: Seems like removing the string from the variable, as suggested in this code solves the problem, what am I missing? see edited codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-leakey-1u72d?file=/Layer.svelte:107-126

Comment: Shimi, in your code, `style = "{styled}"` and `style = {styled}` are the same. In this case, the 4 red frames move as one frame. I want the borders of divs to move smoothly, as is done when calculating the style directly in html. Anyway, thanks for your participation in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had something similar, setting a style attribute via JS
I learned from this today:
https://svelte.dev/repl/4b1c649bc75f44eb9142dadc0322eccd?version=3.6.7

Set CSS in the style block to use a variable.
The variable gets set by JS.

Comment: I will try this method. In this case, I'm wondering why, on the one hand, the same code works differently. For some reason, the style calculated in the <script> is displayed differently than the style calculated in the html block

Comment: @pavel, We can not see the rest of the code in your component. I look at the line starting with `$:` and wonder where ratioTransform , ratioTransform , layerPosition come from. Do those values ever change after the component has mounted?

Comment: ratioTransform and layerPosition are bind from the App.svelte. In App, they are calculated and sent to Layer.svelte

Answer (score 0):

If add in Layer.svelte

```
$: {
    ...
    trX = -y * ratioTransform - ratioTransform*layerPosition*2;
    trY = x * ratioTransform +  ratioTransform*layerPosition*2;
    styled = `transform: rotateX(${trX}deg) rotateY(${trY}deg); transition: transform ${0.4 + layerPosition*0.2}s ease-out;`
```

And `<div style= {styled}></div>` then divs will move smoothly.

P.S. Thank you all for your share.